# Comparing worksheets from a directory of xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file, for-loop

I have a tricky problem trying to compare worksheets in excel files, of which I have many. The problem goes something like this:

I have a directory of about 1000 .xlsx files, each dated sequentially and each with 16 worksheets per file. Each file is a prediction of figures for a particular day that uses data from 4 successive days plus a Saturday from the previous week if it doesn't contain one already.

So for example, if I was predicting the 17th December 2022 the filename would be `xxx_1217.xlsx` and the first 5 worksheets in it would be called something like `['10-12','13-12','14-12','15-12','16-12']`. Where the 10th is a saturday, hence why the 11th and 12th are skipped.

**Lets call this file 1**.

Now the next file in the folder will be the next day, the 18th of December 2022 and contains 4 of the same days plus a new one, which is the actual result (not the day we were predicting) that we were trying to predict so this file will be called `xxx_1218.xlsx` and contain the following 5 sheets `['17-12','13-12','14-12','15-12','16-12']`. The order doesn't matter and the 17th is a Saturday.

**Lets call this file 2**.

Now comes the problem. I want to check that the worksheets in **file 1**, that have the same dates as those in **file 2** contain the exact same data. Then iterate through each successive file and make the same comparison. So after the worksheets of file 1 have been compared to file 2, file 2's worksheets should be compared to file 3 and so forth.

So far I have the following, which does a lot of gymnastics to get the files from the directory, the names of the worksheets, then creates a list of the the relevant ones from the dict. keys and then calls them in dataframes to compare them.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import date

path_root =r'C:\Users\Files'
filenames = [file for file in os.listdir(path_root) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]

keys_list = []
df1_keys_list = []
df2_keys_list = []

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    filename = filenames[i]
    filename_compare = filenames[i+1]
    day = filename[-7:-5]
    month = filename[-9:-7]
    day_compare = filename_compare[-7:-5]
    month_compare = filename_compare[-9:-7]
    filename_compare = 'prealign_debug_'+month_compare+day_compare+'.xlsx'
    Path_1 = os.path.join(path_root,filename)
    Path_2 = os.path.join(path_root,filename_compare)
    df1 = pd.read_excel(Path_1, sheet_name=None)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(Path_2, sheet_name=None)
    for j in df1.keys():
        df1_keys_list.append(j)
    df1_days = df1_keys_list[0:5]
    for k in df2.keys():
        df2_keys_list.append(k)
    df2_days = df2_keys_list[0:5]
    df3 = pd.read_excel(Path_1, sheet_name=df1_days[1])
    df4 = pd.read_excel(Path_1, sheet_name=df1_days[2])
    df5 = pd.read_excel(Path_1, sheet_name=df1_days[3])
    df6 = pd.read_excel(Path_2, sheet_name=df1_days[0])
    df7 = pd.read_excel(Path_2, sheet_name=df1_days[1])
    df8 = pd.read_excel(Path_2, sheet_name=df1_days[2])
    [print('correct') if df3.equals(df6) else print('incorrect')]
    [print('correct') if df4.equals(df7) else print('incorrect')]
    [print('correct') if df5.equals(df8) else print('incorrect')]
```

This is a bit cumbersome, probably there's a slicker way of doing it but this is what I have anyway.

Two problems arise, one: Something is wrong with my loop structure here

```
for j in df1.keys():
        df1_keys_list.append(j)
    df1_days = df1_keys_list[0:5]
```

as the list `df1_keys_list` ends up being 95 elements long when it should be 5. Maybe there is a better way of making the keys list to reference the worksheets?

Secondly, I know its not working, because I'm comparing 5 of the exact same files and when I change an entry in one of them I still get a `'correct'` print statement when I run the script, EXCEPT, when I change an entry in the second file...

How can I tidy this up and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a refactored version of your code, among those I created a compare_file function so that the code is more modular, I converted the keys to lists and took the first 5 elements using list slicing for simplicity, I added if statements inside the loop for common days instead of list comprehensions.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_root = r'C:\Users\Files'
filenames = [file for file in os.listdir(path_root) if file.endswith('.xlsx')]

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1, sheet_name=None)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet_name=None)

    df1_days = list(df1.keys())[:5]
    df2_days = list(df2.keys())[:5]

    common_days = set(df1_days) & set(df2_days)

    for day in common_days:
        if df1[day].equals(df2[day]):
            print(f'{day} in {file1} and {file2} are correct')
        else:
            print(f'{day} in {file1} and {file2} are incorrect')

for i in range(len(filenames) - 1):
    filename1 = os.path.join(path_root, filenames[i])
    filename2 = os.path.join(path_root, filenames[i + 1])
    compare_files(filename1, filename2)
```

Comment: by god that's pretty.